Is possible to automate or auto fill field file in Google Form?
Basically, I want to create a puppeteer so that I can fill in a file in a Google form. All types of fields have been successfully filled in automatically, but file field is fail to fill automatically
I've tried to autofill the file fields, but it fails. Algorithm that I will implement:

Try looking for the "Add File" button
The program will click "Add File"
The modals component will appear
Set files

However, I can't get the "Add File" button.
I use Golang with the Go-Rod package. However, I am open to other programming languages.
